# Why is there a hyphen in ‘to-night’?

Tags: pronunciation, spelling, punctuation, archaic-language, hyphens

> How are you **to-night**, Helen?  Have you coughed much **to-day**?
>   —*Jane Eyre*

Why does *Jane Eyre* have  a hyphen in *to-night*?
Does it signify that the pronunciation in Emily Brontë’s day was [tunáit], not [tənáit], or what?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Per the [Online Etymology Dictionary](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=tonight&allowed_in_frame=0), *tonight* was written as two words until the 18th century, after which it was written with a hyphen until the early 20th century. It's a [similar story](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=today&allowed_in_frame=0) for *today*, except it acquired a hyphen about two centuries earlier.

In other words, when *Jane Eyre* was written, "*to-night*" and "*to-day*" were the correct way to spell these words. They don't denote any difference in pronunciation or meaning.

Comment: This is actually quite strange since tonight was spelt together as one word in Old English (tōniht).

Comment: @JamesJiao, I'm sure it depended on the particular scribe, but Etymonline as well as Dictionary.com say that in Old English it was *to niht*, i.e. two words.

Comment: @JamesJiao What is your source? Bosworth-Toller does not record ‘tóniht’; *s.v.* ***niht*** it offers ‘Tó niht’ translating Vulgate *hac nocte* (Num 22:19), and s.v. ***tilung*** ‘Ðú stunta, tó niht ðú scealt ðín líf álǽtan’ from Wulfstan’s homilies.

Answer (score 8):

*To-day* and *to-night* aren't the only words to have evolved like this.

I'm aware that Ngrams can be [over-used](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=overused,over-used&year_start=1880&year_end=1950&corpus=15&smoothing=5&share=), but, in this case, I think the way [these](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=tonight,%20to-night&year_start=1780&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=5&share=) [Ngrams](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=today,to-day&year_start=1780&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=5&share=) trace the words’ evolution is rather instructive:

[image]

Incidentally, the same thing happened with [*to-morrow*](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=tomorrow,to-morrow&year_start=1780&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=5&share=) as happened with *to-day* and *to-night*.

This [Reuters article](http://www.reuters.com/article/2007/09/21/us-britain-hyphen-idUSHAR15384620070921) might make one think that the demise of the hyphen is a relatively new phenomenon; however, as the Ngrams indicate, hyphens have been prone to vanish for a long time:

> About 16,000 words have succumbed to pressures of the Internet age and lost their hyphens in a new edition of the Shorter Oxford English Dictionary.
>
> Bumble-bee is now bumblebee, ice-cream is ice cream and pot-belly is pot belly.
>
> And if you've got a problem, don't be such a crybaby (formerly cry-baby).
>
> The hyphen has been squeezed as informal ways of communicating, honed in text messages and emails, spread on Web sites and seep into newspapers and books.
>
> "People are not confident about using hyphens anymore, they're not really sure what they are for," said Angus Stevenson, editor of the Shorter OED, the sixth edition of which was published this week.
>
> Another factor in the hyphen's demise is designers' distaste for its ungainly horizontal bulk between words.
>
> "Printed writing is very much design-led these days in adverts and Web sites, and people feel that hyphens mess up the look of a nice bit of typography," he said. "The hyphen is seen as messy looking and old-fashioned."

Comment: Some words which were hyphenated as nouns still need to be hyphenated when used in adjective form.  For example, you can say someone has a _pot belly_, but you'd describe the heater in a room as a _pot-bellied stove_.  Sometimes the latter is called a _pot belly stove_ which, while incorrect under the rules in effect when I learned English, seems to be gaining acceptance.

Answer (score 0):

I remember 'to-day' still being used in the early-mid 1960s... and can see examples of this in TV shows of that era, such as " The Andy Griffith Show" (and many others), where signs & banners can be seen on set, in numerous episodes. As I've been in the sign industry for many years, I tend to notice such things.

Where I remember the conscious change beginning (dropping the hyphen), was when NBC began airing "The Today Show". The 1960s was the start of a major evolutionary change in America and the world.
Of course, logically, English is such a bizarre language anyway (i after e, except after c, or on Thursdays around 3 o'clock)... multiple spellings of the same (sounding) word, dependent on its usage, context, or wind direction. It's... ummm... A great deal more difficult than it needs to be. And that's why I choose to speak American, not English.